# Looking for an easier way, Nhibernate and Repositories?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

This seems like a bunch of extra work for data access. I currently use a generic repository for very basic CRUD, as well I have some specific repository's where I may need to eager load some entities to get around the lovely N+1 anti pattern. Obviously not having N+1 issues makes the database happy. So here is an example of what I have come up with. I would like some feedback and maybe a better way to go about things.

As you can see from the code below my custom repository derives from Repository and I have the interface for the custom repository as well. This all works just seems wrong to me.

```
public class EmailQueueRepository:Repository,IEmailQueueRepository
{
    private readonly ISessionWrapper<ISession> _sessionWrapper;

    public EmailQueueRepository(ISessionWrapper<ISession> sessionWrapper) : base(sessionWrapper)
    {
        _sessionWrapper = sessionWrapper;
    }

    public void AddEmailQueueItem(IEmailQueueItem queueItem)
    {
        _sessionWrapper.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (EmailQueue)).SetFetchMode("User", FetchMode.Eager).SetFetchMode("EmailDeliveryStatus",FetchMode.Eager);
        var emailQueueEntity = new EmailQueue
                                   {
                                       User = _sessionWrapper.Session.QueryOver<User>().Where(u=>u.UserId == queueItem.UserId).SingleOrDefault(),
                                       ToAddress = queueItem.ToAddress,
                                       Subject = queueItem.Subject,
                                       MessageBody = queueItem.MessageBody,
                                       EmailDeliveryStatus = _sessionWrapper.Session.QueryOver<EmailDeliveryStatus>().Where(x=>x.DeliveryStatus=="Pending").SingleOrDefault(),
                                       Active = 1,
                                       DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                                       LastUpdated = DateTime.Now

                                   };
        Insert(emailQueueEntity);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd protected expose your sessionWrapper in your Repository class. Other than that, I don't have anything to add. It's testable which is important.

Comment: However IRepository is in a namespace that is unaware of the SessionWrapper

Comment: Nevermind, thinking too much. I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems wrong to you? This is basically what I do except:

- I don't wrap the ISession and I let my code use the ISession directly for Save, Update, Get and Load operations and to control transactions. My repositories hold predefined queries but the application is free to use the ISession directly.
- I expose the ISession publicly as a read-only property. This makes it possible to new up a second repository from an existing one.
- I don't have a generic repository. I group together related queries and place them in appropriate repositories. For example, queries to retrieve Customer and CustomerStatus both go into a CustomerRepository instead of having one repository per class.

This has worked very well for me and is easily understandable by other developers. In my opinion, the biggest pitfalls to avoid with the repository pattern is having a generic repository and having one repository per class.

Comment: An additional mistake is to abstract away your ORM. This is usually not necessary.

Comment: I am not "abstracting" away the functionality of the ORM, which is why I have the generic repo and then a custom repo as defined in the posted code. I am using the Onion Architecture so ISession will never be used in any of my controllers. I am using a service approach and the Repositories are ctor injected into the services.

Comment: Since you are the only one thus far with an answer and the way I have things setup is not flawed so to say. I will accept this as the answer. Thanks for your comments as well.

Comment: I also have no reference to Nhibernate in my MVC project.